# How to call Oracle function from Hibernate3

Tags: oracle, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have to call a database function whose signature is as below:

```
SF_GET_USER_FROM_STRATEGY(p_strAccountId IN VARCHAR2,p_strUserId IN VARCHAR2 ) 
    RETURN VARCHAR2
```

I am using Hibernate with Annotations. Please suggest me a standard way to call Oracle functions from Hibernate.

Comment: AFAIK Hibernate only supports procedures or functions which returns resultset and you can use sys_refcursor as collection object.

Comment: read about how stored procedures/functions can be called using hibernate 3 here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#sp_query